# objective C blocks equivalent in android

Tags: android, ios

Im looking for the equivalent of the blocks which are present in Objective-C on Android.

Since im looking the best practices of asynchronous data and background threads.

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26115711/how-to-implement-blocks-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no direct equivalent in Java. The closest thing is anonymous listeners, which are local creation and instantiation of a class.

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't support anything like blocks, but depending on what you are trying to accomplish, [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) might suffice.