# how to implement blocks in android

Tags: android, ios, android-asynctask, block

`In IOS we use blocks when we want to handle an action when a particular situation occur`.

Is there a way like this in android to handle situation **onCompletion** and we can add where ever it is.

Like **AsyncTask methods** it knows when work is finish . it executes onPostExecute. How we can create this type of method when a particular situation reach and we handle it like .

**Today i find a way which behave like Blocks in IOS**

```
BaseAsyncTask(new Callback(){

onPostResult(string result)
{
// do whatever you want to do with the result got from asynctaks
}
});
```

it is a delegate and it calls when it reaches a particular situation..

Am i right that the above code is **block in android** as we do in IOS. or there any other way of creating blocks in android.

Comment: Is my answer incorrect? Please provide feedback so that I know how to improve my answer to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have two questions in your question so I will answer them both

> Is there a way like this in android to handle situation onCompletion and we can add where ever it is?
>   How we can create this type of method when a particular situation is reached?

Yes there is a way. I have [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18582807/java-pass-an-executable-block-as-a-parameter) the same thing once here.

In this cases, you use `Runnable`. You use it like so:

```
//creating a runnable block
Runnable block = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //code here
    }
};

//passing it on arguments
doSomething(block); //just like a normal variable

//using it on the method
public void doSomething(Runnable block) {
    block.run();
}
```

Your 2nd question:

```
BaseAsyncTask(new Callback(){

    onPostResult(string result)
    {
        // do whatever you want to do with the result got from asynctaks
    }
});
```

> Am i right that the above code is block in android as we do in IOS. or there any other way of creating blocks in android.

Yes in my opinion, the object `Callback` behaves the same as the blocks in Objective C as I have shown in my previous examples. When the async task is completed (the result is already available) then that Callback is called. Probably like so:

```
callback.onPostResult();
```

Just for your information, the Objects `Runnable` and `Callback` are [java interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html). More on interfaces [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html). If you do not need extra parameters for your callback, you can just use the `Runnable` so as to avoid reinventing the wheel. But if there is something special, i.e. you want to pass paramters to the callback, then you can create your own interface and use it like a `Runnable`.

Comment: glad to be able to help :)

Answer (score 9):

Behave like iOS Block:

A. Let say, in your class **APISingleton** (e.g Volley request-API in singleton class):

1. Define the Interface outside your class:

   ```
   // Callback Blueprint  
   interface APICallback {
       void onResponse(User user, boolean success, String message); // Params are self-defined and added to suit your needs.
   }
   ```
2. In your API-request function

   ```
   public void requestAPIWithURL:(String url, final APICallback callback) {
       // ....
       // After you receive your volley response,
       // Parse the JSON into your model, e.g User model.
       callback.onResponse(user, true, "aloha");  
   }
   ```

B. So, how to call API request and pass your callback function from your activity, or fragment, is like this:

```
APISingleton.getInstance().requestAPIWithURL("http://yourApiUrl.com", new APICallback() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(User user, boolean success, String message) {
            // you will get your user model, true, and "aloha" here
            mUser = user;
            Log.v(TAG, "success:" + success);
            Log.v(TAG, "aloha or die?" + message);

            // Your adapter work. :D
        }
    });
```